# How to make a grid like in the Instagram explore page?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, instagram

What is the best way to implement a grid inside a `recycler view` having a larger view holder in between the list at some pre-specified positions?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

hello well this library could help you its awesome
https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView